# Error in video streaming using libavformat: VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, libavcodec, libavformat

I stream a video using libavformat as follows:

```
static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec **codec,
                        enum AVCodecID codec_id)
{
AVCodecContext *c;
AVStream *st;
/* find the encoder */
*codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
if (!(*codec)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
            avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
    exit(1);
}
st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
if (!st) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
    exit(1);
}
st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
c = st->codec;
switch ((*codec)->type) {
case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
    c->sample_fmt  = (*codec)->sample_fmts ?
        (*codec)->sample_fmts[0] : AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    c->bit_rate    = 64000;
    c->sample_rate = 44100;
    c->channels    = 2;
    break;
case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
    c->codec_id = codec_id;
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
    c->width    = outframe_width;
    c->height   = outframe_height;
    /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
     * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
     * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
     * identical to 1. */
    c->time_base.den = STREAM_FRAME_RATE;
    c->time_base.num = 1;
    c->gop_size      = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
    c->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
    if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
        /* just for testing, we also add B frames */
        c->max_b_frames = 2;
    }
    if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
        /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
         * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
         * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
        c->mb_decision = 2;
    }
break;
default:
    break;
}
/* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
return st;
}
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error/warning:

```
[mpeg @ 01f3f040] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
```

Do you know how I can set the VBV buffer size in the code? In fact, when I use ffplay to display the streamed video, ffplay doesn't show anything for short videos but for long videos, it start displaying the video immediately. So, it looks like ffplay needs a buffer to be filled up by some amount so that it can start displaying the stream. Am I right?

Comment: looks like it's set here, if that helps. https://github.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mpegenc.c#L390 I know in the past ffplay has introduced its own latency so...it's possible it needs some kind of buffer.  --fflags nobuffer might help? (sounds like a bug in ffplay to me tho...)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the VBV buffer size of a stream with:

```
AVCPBProperties *props;
props = (AVCPBProperties*) av_stream_new_side_data(
    st, AV_PKT_DATA_CPB_PROPERTIES, sizeof(*props));
props->buffer_size = 230 * 1024;
props->max_bitrate = 0;
props->min_bitrate = 0;
props->avg_bitrate = 0;
props->vbv_delay = UINT64_MAX;
```

Where `st` is a pointer to the `AVStream` struct. Min bit rate, max bit rate, and average bit rate are set to 0 while the VBV delay is set to `UINT64_MAX` in this example because those values indicate unknown or unspecified values for these fields (see [AVCPB properties documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVCPBProperties.html)). Alternatively, you set these values to whatever is reasonable for your specific use case. Just don't forget to assign these fields, because they will not be initialized automatically.

Comment: what happens to this pointer (AVCPBProperties *props;)? Do we have to keep it and release it later, or does it belong to AVStream so it will be released when st is destroyed?